# php error accessing double layer array

Tags: php, arrays

My data is in a second tier of a return value that I am trying to access the individual elements.  Array ( [success] => 1 [return] => Array ( [0] => Array 
I tried ['return'] since it is the key of that, is what I need but got the same error or obvious worse.

error:

```
Array to string conversion in orders.php on line 10
```

code:

```
<?php
 $id = $argv[1];  //variable for inbound
 require_once('phpPlay.php');
 $result = api_query("mytrades", array("marketid" => $id));
 foreach( $result as $x) {
                echo $x;
 }

?>
```

data top 5 rows:

```
Array
(
    [success] => 1
    [return] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [tradeid] => 74038377
                    [tradetype] => Sell
                    [datetime] => 2014-11-12 16:05:32
                    [tradeprice] => 0.00675000
                    [quantity] => 22.18670000
                    [fee] => -0.00007488
                    [total] => 0.14976023
                    [initiate_ordertype] => Buy
                    [order_id] => 197009493
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [tradeid] => 73687280
                    [tradetype] => Buy
                    [datetime] => 2014-11-09 03:38:13
                    [tradeprice] => 0.00816988
                    [quantity] => 0.00100000
                    [fee] => 0.00000002
                    [total] => 0.00000817
                    [initiate_ordertype] => Buy
                    [order_id] => 194824864
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [tradeid] => 73684313
                    [tradetype] => Sell
                    [datetime] => 2014-11-09 02:57:41
                    [tradeprice] => 0.00808034
                    [quantity] => 0.00100000
                    [fee] => 0.00000000
                    [total] => 0.00000808
                    [initiate_ordertype] => Buy
                    [order_id] => 194803992
                )

            [3] => Array
                (
                    [tradeid] => 73653019
                    [tradetype] => Sell
                    [datetime] => 2014-11-08 17:53:12
                    [tradeprice] => 0.00793991
                    [quantity] => 0.00010000
                    [fee] => 0.00000000
                    [total] => 0.00000079
                    [initiate_ordertype] => Buy
                    [order_id] => 194559503
                )

            [4] => Array
                (
                    [tradeid] => 73652717
                    [tradetype] => Sell
                    [datetime] => 2014-11-08 17:50:13
                    [tradeprice] => 0.00793989
                    [quantity] => 0.00100000
                    [fee] => 0.00000002
                    [total] => 0.00000794
                    [initiate_ordertype] => Sell
                    [order_id] => 194559596
                )
```

...

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do here, but if you're trying to print the contents of array, you should use `print_r`

Comment: you could just use the function print_r()

Comment: I have to copy values to a hash table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that with the `echo $x` statement in your code above, `$x` is an array, not a string.

The `echo` function requires a string, so the error you're getting is because PHP is automatically trying to convert the parameter passed to `echo` to a string, but it is failing because you are passing an array.

Try this:

```
if (isset($result['return'])) {
    foreach($result['return'] as $result_item) {
        echo(var_export($result_item, true));
    }
} else {
    echo 'No results';
}
```

Comment: That's it! I was close and everywhere around it. But that's what I was looking for.